# Test Environment not loading latest code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test-environments

When i am running my rails app in development env everything looks fine,
below is a screenshot of signup page in development env 
[image: this is a screenshot of signup page in development env]

BUt when i run my rails webrick server in test env :
Signup page in test env
[image: Signup page in test env]

I can't figure out why test env is not able to load latest code.My `config/environments/development.rb` file looks like the following:

```
Rails.application.configure do

# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files  = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener

  # config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'test_orthograph_session'

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
  config.ip = 'http://localhost:3000'
end
```

my `config/environments/test.rb` looks like the following:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files   = false
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'
  config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Randomize the order test cases are executed.
  config.active_support.test_order = :random

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

I am using `rails 4.2.10` & `ruby 2.4.1`.
I have tried running rake `assets:precompile` with no effect.
The same issue is in production environment also, old code is loading in production setup.

Edit: Adding github pull request link here.
https://github.com/rakesh-1010/todoappp/pull/1

Link to repo: https://github.com/rakesh-1010/todoappp/tree/todoapp

Answer (score 0):

Set `config.serve_static_files` to true in test.rb and production.rb and restart your Rails server.

Comment: did you try compiling for those environments? `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test` (for the test env, for example); can you put an example of an app that has this problem up on github?
 depending on how you structured your assets there's a million things it could be.

Comment: Hi Josh , I tried precompiling assets in test env, it didn't work as well, i have updated my question with a pull request of my project.If you have time do look into it and help

Comment: @Supertracer  rakesh my friend :) good news! You simply need to move the `erb2haml` and `haml` gems out of your `group :development` block in your Gemfile. Place them into the general space — directly below your `rails` gem, for example. Then `bundle install` and restart your server :)